# Why isn't bash splitting fields inside $() operator?

Tags: bash

Just for the sake of learning, while I was trying a bunch of stuff, I noticed a `bash` behavior that I couldn't logically explain.

```
$ ls $(echo a)
ls: cannot access 'a': No such file or directory

$ ls $($'\145\143\150\157\40\141')
echo a: command not found

$ ls $($"\145\143\150\157\40\141")
\145\143\150\157\40\141: command not found
```

In the first case, `echo a` was being evaluated to `a` which becomes an argument to `ls`. Fair enough. However, in the second case, the octal encoded string was being evaluated to `echo a` as expected; but the entire string was being treated as the command by `$()`. Moreover, in the third case, no expansion is taking place with double quotes. Why don't the fields split? I guess it has got something to do with [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) in `bash`. But, I failed to explain what could the exact problem be. Is there any way I can make the field splitting work so that it gets treated like the first case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A word of the form `$'string'` is expanded to a single-quoted string, as if the dollar sign had not been present. That means,

```
$($'\145\143\150\157\40\141')
```

is the same as

```
$('echo a')
```

And single-quoted strings don't undergo word splitting or any other kind of expansion. See [Bash Reference Manual § ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

> Is there any way I can make the field splitting work so that it gets treated like the first case?

```
$ ls $(eval $'\145\143\150\157\40\141')
ls: cannot access 'a': No such file or directory
```

This is inadvisable though, see [BashFAQ#048](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

---

Concerning `$"string"` syntax, see [Bash Reference Manual § Locale-Specific Translation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Locale-Translation), it's whole another thing.